# Trigger to update all existing record with same Account name at time of insertion

Tags: apex, trigger

I am writing a trigger to update all my existing account records if new record is with same name created(which exits already in account records). But  it is not working properly, sometimes it update and sometimes not.

Here is code,

```
trigger AccountTrigger  on Account (after insert,before update){
    Map<String, Account> mapAccount = new Map<String, Account>();
    Set<String> setAccName = new Set<String>();
    List<Id> accountIdlist= new List<Id>();
    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        setAccName.add(acc.Name);
        accountIdlist.add(acc.Id);
    }
    // Add the fields you need to update on the query below.
    for (Account acc :[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :setAccName limit 1]) {
        mapAccount.put(acc.Name, acc);
        mapAccount.put(acc.Id, acc);
    }

    List<Account> forUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    List<Id> forDeleteList = new List<Id>();

    for(Account acc : trigger.new) {
        if (mapAccount.containsKey(acc.Name) && mapAccount.get(acc.Name).Id != acc.Id ) {
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Id = mapAccount.get(acc.Name).Id;
            a.AccountNumber=acc.AccountNumber;
            forUpdateList.add(a);
            forDeleteList.add(acc.Id);
        }
    }

    if (!forUpdateList.isEmpty()) {
        update forUpdateList;
    }

    if (!forDeleteList.isEmpty()) {
        delete [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN :forDeleteList];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (Account acc :[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :setAccName limit 1]) {
```

You're only querying one record, regardless of the volume of matches in the database and the number of Accounts in the trigger set. Remove the `LIMIT` clause here.

Additionally, I think you're going to see unexpected behavior if your database contains *existing* duplicates. Your code selects one more or less at random. It does not update all records of a given name. You'd need to be working with a `Map<String, List<Account>>` to achieve that.

I'd really recommend you consider using native [Duplicate Management](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management) functionality for this process. It is a no-code solution that is intended to prevent duplicates from being added in the first place.

Comment: Instead Map<String,List<Account>> if i use Map<String,List<Account>> then how i have to add logic here,
     
   if (mapAccount.containsKey(acc.Name) && mapAccount.get(acc.Name).Id != acc.Id ) {
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Id = mapAccount.get(acc.Name).Id;